# Jfrog XRay: report CVE-2022-29458 on the package 6.3-2ubuntu0.1

Tags: jfrog-xray

I am using JFrog Xray to scan for security issues in my project. There is a vulnerability issue CVE-2022-29458 with high level need to resolve.

```
| SEVERITY | DIRECT                    | DIRECT  | IMPACTED                  | IMPACTED               | FIXED    | TYPE   | CVE            |
|          | PACKAGE                   | PACKAGE | PACKAGE                   | PACKAGE                | VERSIONS |        |                |
|          |                           | VERSION | NAME                      | VERSION                |          |        |                |
+----------+---------------------------+---------+---------------------------+------------------------+----------+--------+----------------+
| High   | sha256__01d4e4b4f381ac5a9 |         | ubuntu:jammy:libncurses6  | 6.3-2ubuntu0.1         |          | Debian | CVE-2022-29458
```

However, the docker image is up-to-date and comes with the package 6.3-2ubuntu0.1 that should not be vulnerable according to the page https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-6099-1 and http://launchpadlibrarian.net/666970387/ncurses_6.3-2_6.3-2ubuntu0.1.diff.gz

Answer (score 0):

What version of Xray are you using and what is your db-sync status?

Looking in Xray Database, CVE-2022-29458 on ubuntu:jammy:ncurses has low severity and the fixed version is indeed 6.3-2ubuntu0.1.
So we can suspect that either your db-sync is not updated and therefore you're getting this result or the component is somehow identified wrongly which requires more investigation.